# Rails 3 able to import/export to/from Microsoft Access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ms-access

this question has been asked here already but it's quite some time ago. Does anyone know if Rails has any support for Microsoft Access? I'd need to import and export data every few weeks and would really like to avoid exporting/importing csv files.

Thanks!

Comment: which version of ms-access do you use?

Comment: 2003 but could change it to another version if needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth noting that there's an `mdb` gem for Ruby.  It requires [mdbtools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/) to be installed.

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mdb'
```

Usage is pretty straightforward, tables are basically lists of hashes:

```
require 'mdb'

database = Mdb.open('workshops_handouts_inactive_database.mdb')
table = database[:MainData]
results = table.select { |rec| rec[:"Schedule Type"] == "MU1" }
puts results.first

{:"Container Number"=>"17", :Location=>"1f6", :Department=>"tx", ...
```

I don't think ActiveRecord support exists for MS Access, though.

Answer (score 1):

the win32OLE class allows you to retrieve data from Microsoft Acess you can find the docs here
http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html

Comment: I found that one already but to me it seems its only for Excel?

Comment: Nope it works with access too here a old link http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-ruby-ado-to-work-with-ms-access.html that might help you out